# Access to the same memory adress through two parallel application in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I have two applications.

First application:

```
int a = 42;
int *P = &a;
```

Second application:

```
int b = *P;
```

Is it possible to do that? Otherwise, is it possible to access the same memory through two applications (or multiple) that are executed in parallel?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory

Comment: Generally speaking, if there is __any other way__ to do what you're trying to do, do it. Shared memory between processes can be pretty difficult to do. What if they communicated over a common network protocol? What if they both accessed a database?

Comment: The shared memory part is the easy part.  The hard part is synchronization.  At the point where you're sharing memory, you have a lot of the same problems as you would in a threaded app (since the biggest difference between threads and processes in most systems is the isolation of memory, and you're choosing to get rid of that).

Comment: Or even just a common file on the disk.

Comment: @Chad - good point, especially given memory-mapped file APIs.

Comment: @Peter I am working on windows :-)

Comment: I did tested it using the dev c++, and the problem was that the compiler returns an error in the second application saying that the pointer points to nothing

Comment: @Henry, yeah of course I will my friend, but wanna feed my curiosity in the subject :-)

Comment: The other way is to change data between apps using xml or databases, or just a simple file... but this requires to update the file everytime you want to use da variable in the 2nd app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two separate applications, even the shared memory bit involves more than referencing through the same address, certainly on typical desktop systems. Each application sees a virtual address space - not the physical address space of the machine. The memory for other applications usually isn't even visible - let alone mapped to the same address.

There are (platform specific) APIs that can give you some access to another applications memory, aimed mainly at debuggers and similar tools, but also e.g. used by games "trainer" cheats - but this isn't a good way to communicate between apps.

On Windows...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, It seems logical..but all I want to do is to find a way changing data between parallel applications without using xml file, or database.. just using memory...

Comment: @Simo: I would suggest reading up on "IPC" or "Inter-Process Communication".  Shared memory may be the right way to solve your particular problem, but it might not.

Comment: @Simo - maybe what you want is a pipe? A lot of platforms will allow you to create one of these. From one end it's like an append-only file. From the other it's like a read-only file. However, there is no file. Alternatively, you can create kinda-shared memory by using memory mapped file APIs - though there are synchronization issues. The trouble is, what seems like a simple problem really never is. If you take a shortcut, you will probably end up in trouble later. Even those game trainer programs quite often cause the game to crash.